# In Python, assign entries of dictionaries dynamically

Tags: python, dictionary

In the code below, I have a dictionary "John" which I assign a value to with a certain key ("phone number"):

```
John={}
statement='John'+"['phone number']=123456"
exec statement
```

The reason I did it with "exec" like above is because the actual dictionary "John" and "phone number" are supposed to vary within a for loop. This works, but is not very elegant; I'd rather like to do something similar to

```
vars()['John'+'_phone_number']=123456
```

because in this case, you don't run the risk of the "exec" statement failing if the syntax is not right. (What I'd like to achieve is similar to Matlab's "assignin" function, except for dictionary entries).

Is there a way of defining entries of a dictionary without using "exec"?

Comment: Can you put all dictionaries in a list and then manipulate the right dict using a combination of list indexing and dictionary assignment? Or even have a dict of dicts?

Comment: Why not using a dictionary of people whose entries are dictionaries with people's info ? Instead you insist on using your local variables name space as a dictionary...

Comment: Why do people always want to do this? Keep your data out of your variable names, and just use a nested dictionary.

Comment: In general, if you need your program to know the name there is going to be a better way to do it.

Comment: Your question isn't clear to me. Could you provide more detail on what you mean by "supposed to vary with a loop". Are you reading a file or something and looping over the lines of the file? IOW, what is going on in your loop?

Comment: If you insist on not using a dict of dicts, there's always locals(), however, the docs say to try to avoid writing to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should use a dictionary of dictionaries.  You can even employ a `defaultdict` to avoid needing to precondition each entry for each individual user.

```
from collections import defaultdict

users = defaultdict(dict)
users['John']['phone number'] = 123456
```

Comment: As Travis Griggs noted, my question is not so clearly stated, so I'll accept this answer though in the event I used the 'not-so-elegant' solution I had already started with (see my answer below). I find nested dictionaries somewhat cumbersome, but I suppose this is a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

I think `defaultdict` is a bad idea here ... Im pretty sure all users should have the same keys (eg all users should be a phone number and email , or a user_id or the same keys for every user

```
users = {}
for name,phone,email in [("john","123","a@b"),("mary","432","b@b"),...]:
    users[name] = dict(email=email,phone=phone)
```

or if you are going to use default dict at least ensure that it has all the required fields of a user

```
def my_user_dict():
    return {"email":"","phone":""}

users = defaultdict(my_user_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it seems that the majority feels the way to go is using nested dictionaries - and I'll accept this answer - in my own code I decided to stick with the not-so-elegant way using the "exec" statement. The code - which actually is not for users and phone numbers, but is to determine and store mathematical attributes of certain curves - is shown below:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# CSV file generated from nDI by Data Export -> ASCII with "Export as CSV" ticked on
filename="lnb.1t_LNB-1_wedge_amplitude_extractions.csv"

# Read column headers (to be variable names)
with open(filename) as f:
    firstline = f.readline()                    # Read first line of csv
    firstline = firstline.replace("\n","")      # Remove new line characters
    firstline = firstline.replace(" ","")       # Remove spaces
    ColumnHeaders = firstline.split(",")        # Get array of column headers

# Read in the data (omitting the first row containing column headers)
data=np.loadtxt(filename,skiprows=1,delimiter=",")

N_leg=50        # Number of traces 'pure' gas leg and brine leg

# Assign the data to arrays, with names of the variables generated from column headers
Ind=0                                       # Initialize counter
for Var in ColumnHeaders:
    vars()[Var]=data[:,Ind]                 # Create an array for each column, named after the corresponding column header
    if Var.endswith("_evnt_amp"):           # For columns with headers containing the suffix '_evnt_amp' ('event amplitude'):
        Event=Var.strip("_evnt_amp")        # Define a string containing the event name
        vars()[Event]={}                    # Initialize an empty dictionary
        statement1=Event+"['gas leg amplitude']=np.mean(data[0:N_leg,Ind])"
        exec statement1
        statement2=Event+"['brine leg amplitude']=np.mean(data[-N_leg:-1,Ind])"
        exec statement2
        statement3=Event+"['gas to brine leg ratio']=np.mean(data[0:N_leg,Ind])/np.mean(data[-N_leg:-1,Ind])"
        exec statement3
##        vars()[Var+'_gas_leg']=data[0:N_leg,Ind]
##        vars()[Var+'_brine_leg']=data[-N_leg:-1,Ind]
##        vars()[Var.strip('_evnt_amp')+'_gas_leg_amplitude']=np.mean(data[0:N_leg,Ind])
##        vars()[Var.strip('_evnt_amp')+'_brine_leg_amplitude']=np.mean(data[-N_leg:-1,Ind])
    Ind=Ind+1                               # Increment counter

plt.close('all')

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(Bin,ROSLU_T_evnt_amp,'c')
plt.plot(Bin,-DC_T_evnt_amp,'m')
plt.xlabel('Bin')
plt.ylabel('|Amplitude|')
plt.legend(['ROSLU_T','DC_T'])

plt.show()
```

The relevant part is the for loop with the "exec" statements. (I've commented out the 'obsolete' lines below them, which work by appending suffixes instead of creating a dictionary).

After running this code, I can for example at the command line type the name of an event, and read several of its attributes:

```
>>> ROSLU_T
{'gas to brine leg ratio': 2.1782322499999998, 'gas leg amplitude': 174.25857999999997, 'brine leg amplitude': 80.0}
```

For reference I've pasted a part of the input csv file below:

Track, Bin, ZEZ2A_T_evnt_amp,RO_T_evnt_amp,ROSLU_T_evnt_amp,DC_T_evnt_amp
              1,              1,    -1288.4139,      999.9983,      174.1523,     -201.6915
              1,              2,    -1288.4139,      999.9983,      174.1523,     -201.6915
              1,              3,    -1288.4139,      999.9983,      174.1523,     -201.6915
              1,              4,    -1288.4139,      999.9983,      174.1523,     -201.6915
              1,              5,    -1288.4139,      999.9983,

The plot generated by this code is shown below.

[image: wedge model amplitude extractions]

Comment: You'll probably get downvoted for this (terrible) code.  Also, please follow PEP 8.

Comment: And… `strip` doesn't do what you think it does.